# Battle.net won't launch after latest update

Tags: 16.04, games

Is anyone else having problems with Battle.net not launching after latest patch?  Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't know why someone would down vote your question, I up voted it for you. You should include more information though if you want help. Are you using wine proper? What version? Are you using instead PlayonLinux or Crossover Office? etc.  Also what patch are you talking about? Battle.net,  A blizzard game, wine, Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, I verified on my end if I could open battle.net, and I had no problem. http://imgur.com/a/ZDWuX. I'm using Crossoveroffice 15.1.0. Mostly because I'm too lazy to fsck with wine.

Comment: I'm using Crossover Linux 15.1 and had WoW up and running with no problems.  Crossover uses Wine 1.8 and can't be updated.  The last time I tried to launch WoW through Battle.net the box appeared about a Battle.net required update, click to relaunch.  I clicked the relaunch button, Battle.net closed and never reopened.  I clicked the shortcut and nothing happened. I tried changing video drivers and none of them worked. I'm using the recommended driver 361.42. I deleted the WoW bottle in Crossover and tried to reinstall. Now Battle.net doesn't install. I've been using Ubuntu for about a month.

Comment: Are you using Wine? The executable does not launch? Servers are offline? What is the specific question?

Comment: I'll try to install WoW later and see if it works. If you are using a legal copy of Crossover, it comes with free tech support, so you may want to contact support.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the folder 7730 which is the newest update and it will work fine.

But when you get inside the battle.net, stop the updates.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found the following on WineHQ, I haven't tried that yet, but I hope this fixes it.

I'm having problems too. After the last update today playonlinux complains like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Sqm.png)

I tried reinstalling battlenet but no luck. I do have the mscorefonts installed (that fixed the last similar crash) so it can't be that.

As of July 27 2016

Battle.net Patch 1.4.3 Build 7730

Wine 1.9.14

These steps are required:

```
Create standard directory for WINEPREFIXes

mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/wineprefixes

Create new 32-bit WINEPREFIX

env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.local/share/wineprefixes/bnet wineboot -u

Download latest Winetricks

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks

Make it executable

chmod +x winetricks

Install vcrun2015

env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.local/share/wineprefixes/bnet ./winetricks -q vcrun2015

Download latest Battle.net installer

wget "https://eu.battle.net/download/getInstaller?os=win&installer=Battle.net-Setup.exe" -O bnetsetup.exe

Install Battle.net

env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.local/share/wineprefixes/bnet wine bnetsetup.exe
```

Comment: I moved your EDIT answer found sentence to the top, so it would look like an answer and not a question.

Comment: Right. Well, I followed the steps from WineHQ guide and it worked almost fine afterwards. I now have a medium severity issue when I quit the game, where the whole xfce desktop freezes and I have to CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE and log in again. That wasn't happening before the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a video on youtube that suggested to install steam. I did and it seems to work. It must install something that battle.net was missing.